# Reversing and combining a list

Tags: java, loops, iterator, set

I have the following list:

> list 1= 1,2,3,4,5,6

I am trying to make a list that contains the following:

> list c= 1,6,2,5,3,4

However, I cannot figure out how to do it. I know how to iterate through 6 but I don't know how to get to the last number and iterate backwards. I know a ListIterator can be used to go backwards but I still cannot figure it out.

This is what I did to add the original, I just don't understand how to iterate backwards:

```
public static void q(Set<String>list1)
{
    Set<String>combined = new HashSet();
    Iterator<String> forward = list1.iterator();
    Iterator <String> backwards = list1.iterator();

    for (int i=0; i<list1.size(); i++)
    {
        combined.add(forward.next());

        //code to go backwards
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: I added what I have. However, is not useful at all. I do not know how to iterate backwards. @f1sh

Comment: A `Set` isn't really the right data type if you want a specific order.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Algo would be

1.) just use two positions , `i =0` for increment and `j = size-1` for decrements

2.) add elements to new list using `i` and `j` positions while traversing to the middle of the content list

```
Integer []aa=new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5,6};
List<Integer> list =Arrays.asList(aa);
int n=list.size();
List<Integer> list2 =new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0,j=list.size()-1; i <n/2 ; i++,j--) {
        list2.add(list.get(i));
        list2.add(list.get(j));        
    }
//    if(n%2!=0) list2.add(list.get(n/2)); // un-comment this , to handle 
                                          // odd list size too ,dynamism 

list2.forEach(i->System.err.print(i+" "));
```

Output:

```
1 6 2 5 3 4
```

Comment: No idea why none of the answers got accepted or even upvoted; but yours looks quite good. So lets do what i can do about it.

Comment: @GhostCat sure dude and maybe OP got confused or busy :P

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you simply want to put the last element of the first list on the second index, you can do something like:

```
 List<Integer> input = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

 // create new list that initially contains first and last element of input list
 List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(input.get(0), input.get(input.size()-1)));

 // now iterate the "in between" input elements and add them to output
 for (int i=1; i < input.size() -1 ; i++) {
   output.add(input.get(i));
 }

 System.out.println("in: " + input);
 System.out.println("out: " + output);
```

Of course, the above is just one way of doing this; there are many others

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your exactly looking for and where your code has broke. You could try:

```
List<Integer> intergers = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
    if(i < 6) {
        intergers.add((i-1), i);
    } else {
        intergers.add(1, i); //when i is 6 place it in the second index                 
    }
}
System.out.println("List: " + intergers.toString());
```

With java list you can chose the index and if that index has a value the value well be pushed to the next index. It was the simplest thing I could think of. This is what it printed out:

> List: [1, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: No idea why none of the answers got accepted or even upvoted; but yours looks quite good. So lets do what i can do about it. But: using *x* as name for an int counter is really bad practice. Better use i, j, k for such indexes!

Comment: Updated to use 'i'. Also was never told 'x' was bad practice, so thanks.

Comment: Probably more of an implicit convention. You see, when doing math, and dealing with "whole numbers", you typically use i, j, ... whereas when dealing with rational numbers, you go for x, and f(x), and so on. One might be tempted to use x, y, z, ... as indexes when iterating multi-dim arrays though.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't to solve your problem, but rather to show you how `ListIterator` can be used to go backwards since you couldn't figure it out.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int n = 1; n <= 6; n++) { // Add 1, 2, ... 6 to list
    list.add(n);
}

ListIterator it = list.listIterator(list.size());
while (it.hasPrevious()) {
    System.out.println(it.previous());
}
```

The `listIterator` method of a `List` allows you to specify the index to start at as a parameter.
The `hasPrevious` method of the `ListIterator` checks if there is a previous element (self-explanitory).
The `previous()` method of the `ListIterator` returns the previous element in the list and moves the cursor position backwards.

Using `ListIterator` you can go forwards and backwards as you please using `next()` and `previous()` respectively.

Alternatively, using a for statement instead of using `ListIterator`...

```
for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

Comment: No idea why none of the answers got accepted or even upvoted; but yours looks quite good. So lets do what i can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you really wanted a Set given you were talking about lists. This is the idea without explicitly using list iterators however they would behave the similarly.

How to use a list iterator: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/ListIteratorInreverseorder.htm

```
public static List<Integer> interleaveFrontBack(List<Integer> list) {

    if (list.size() <= 2){
        return new LinkedList<Integer>(list);
    }

    List interleaved = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    int end = list.size() - 1;
    int front = 0;

    while (end > front){
        interleaved.add(list.get(front++));
        interleaved.add(list.get(end--));
    }

    // if odd sized list need to add last element
    if (end == front){
        interleaved.add(list.get(front));
    }

    return interleaved;
}
```

Comment: No idea why none of the answers got accepted or even upvoted; but yours looks quite good. So lets do what i can do about it.